# Breaking My Long WPA2-PSK password

Tags: kali-linux, wpa2-psk

I have been trying to crack my wifi password via kali linux. I have used aircrack, hashcat, and reaver, all of which have failed. Reaver failed due to the AP locking, but hashcat and aircrack failed due to the fact that the password was long and numerical around 25 characters (lack of processing power). Is there any better tool or form of attack that is not brute-force or dictionary to break my wifi-pass?

Thanks

Comment: JOOI, what is the password, so that we can check its entropy for you? ;)

Comment: Why do you need to crack the password? There may be an alternative to cracking it which would suit you better. A long password is going to take a long time to crack.

Comment: @Dan Griffin Could you please provide some of the alternatives? Thank you

Comment: @Andrew Morton I'm not worried if it's super secure. I'm trying to learn about kali linux and just testing.

Comment: @dylan7 It looks like you passed the "social engineering" method test of cracking the password :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the back of your Wi-fi router, and press the tiny reset,button and the password is now default.
2. If you had a high end GPU you could use a opencl,cuda,steam processor acceleration on a brute force.

   The short version **see you in 1000 years** when your brute force gets there.

   You might be able to find a bug in your routers OS, and exploit that.  Google your router for security bugs and you **might** find an exploit.